# Arquitectura en capas en ASP.NET MVC usando Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, arquitectura

Queria consultarles si estoy realizando bien el uso de una arquitectura en capas, porque encontre en varios lados que la hacen diferente y me entraron dudas. 
Tengo una solucion en Visual Studio, usando C#, SQL Server y EF como ORM y use este tipo de arquitectura.

Capa de datos <- Capa logica negocio <- Capa presentacion
      !               !                    !
Capa entidades<-----------------------------

En la capa de datos tengo EF, y unicamente lo uso para eso, para tener el elemento ADO.Net de EF. La capa de logica de negocio, es la que uso para traer los datos y usar por ejemplo db.SaveChanges() o db.Add(), etc (instrucciones de EF). Y la capa de presentacion es donde tengo el proyecto de MVC. 
Todas apuntan a la capa de entidades que es donde guardo mis modelos (y no en la capa de presentacion con el proyecto de MVC)

Son dos preguntas las que quiero resolver:

1- Esta bien que en la capa de negocios use las intrucciones de EF como context.SaveChanges() o context.Add()?

2- Esta bien usar los modelos en una capa transversal? Hago esto, para que todas las capas puedan usar estos modelos, ya que si dejo modelos en la de Datos, la de presentacion no los podria usar. Y en caso de que este bien, yo lo que hago por ejemplo para traer un registro de la db, es traerlo con el modelo que tiene EF, y despues crear un objeto con el modelo que tengo en la Capa Entidades, y eso llevarlo hasta la Capa de presentacion.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El enfoque que propones es perfectamente válido y aporta un buen diseño, pero en mi opinión, podrías ahorrarte la **capa de entidades**.

En cuanto a las preguntas:

> 1- ¿Esta bien que en la capa de negocios use las intrucciones de EF como context.SaveChanges() o context.Add()?

Si por supuesto, la capa de negocio o **capa de servicios** es la que se encargará de mantener la **persistencia** con la base de datos a través del **ORM** (Entity Framework en tu caso). En ella debes definir los **métodos** encargados de intercambiar la información entre tu aplicación MVC y la base de datos.

> 2- ¿Está bien usar los modelos en una capa transversal?

Podrías hacerlo, pero yo te aconsejo que los **modelos** los mantengas en la **capa de datos**, tal y como los gestiona EF, o sea, como entidades **mapeadas** directamente como están definidas en la base de datos.

Posteriormente si quieres utilizar estos modelos en la **capa de presentación** (aplicación MVC) puedes utilizar los que en la arquitectura ASP.NET MVC se llaman **ViewModels**. Estos **ViewModels**, estarán definidos en la **capa de presentación** y estarán construidos a partir de los **modelos** de la **capa de datos**.

La **estructura en capas** que yo utilizo habitualmente es la siguiente:

Partimos de una solución **MiSolución**, que contendrás **tres proyectos**:

**1 - Proyecto MiProyecto.Data:**

Aquí definiremos todo lo relacionado con el ORM (EF). Los **Modelos** mapeados de la BD, el contexto de datos (**DbContext**), el histórico de **Migraciones** etc. 
Esta sería tu **capa de datos**.

**2 - Proyecto MiProyecto.Services:**

Aquí definiremos todo lo relacionado con la lógica de negocios. Definirías las clases de servicio que se conectan con la base de datos a través de EF. Esta sería tu **capa de negocio**.

***Nota***: Por supuesto, esta capa recibiría de la **capa de datos** una **instancia** del contexto de datos (**DbContext**), por ejemplo mediante **inyección de dependencias**.

**3 - Proyecto MiProyecto.Web:**

Aquí estaría definida la aplicación ASP.NET MVC, con su Vistas y Controladores.
Y es aquí donde puedes incluir lo que tu llamas **capa de entidades** como modelos del tipo **ViewModel**.

Los modelos del tipo **ViewModel**, serán los que se **intercambien** entre las **vistas** y los **controladores**, y **NO** los modelos que se encuentran en la **capa de datos**.

***Nota***: te dejo la [dirección](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/managing-data-with-viewmodel-in-asp-net-mvc/) de un artículo (en inglés) donde puedes ver cómo trabajar con **ViewModels** en ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 3):

Al parecer tu modelo de capas esta bien, solamente te aconsejaría no acceder al contexto directamente sino usar el patrón de diseño de repositorio y unit of work que serian unas clases intermedias entre tu contexto y tu capa de negocios como una mejor practica.

El tener modelos en un proyecto aparte es correcto ya que como comentas es una manera de tenerlos disponibles para las diferentes capas. Para mapear tus entidades de EF a tu modelo te recomiendo usa Automapper es muy facil de configurar y te evitas mucho codigo para mapear entidades a modelos manualmente.

Saludos y espero poder haber ayudado.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Ahora voy a ver bien lo del Automapper, que tiene buena pinta porque por ahora mis proyectos fueron con entidades muy pequeñas como maximo 6 o 7 propiedades cada una, pero si llego a tener una muy grande se puede hacer muy pesado lo de pasarlo al modeo. G

Comment: No importa si es grande o pequeña, es el numero de entidades que tengas que mapear, si sabes que van a ser muchas te recomiendo implementarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Usar el `dbcontext` desde la capa de negocio puede o no estar bien dependiendo de que tan complejo es lo que tengas que desarrollar

Se suele usar una capa de `repository`, pero esta mas bien con el objetivo de inyectar la interface en el servicio de negocio y poder aplicar `mocks` del repostiory para poder desarrollar `unit test`

Quizas si no tienes pensado crear test del codigo y quieres algo rapido podrias evitar el `repository`, las versiones mas nueva de `entity framework` permiten configurar un dbcontext en memoria con lo cual podrias emular una db sin que acceda fisicamente, con esto podrias crear test

Puede llegar hasta el `controller` la entidad que mapeaste con `entity framework` pero no deberias devolver esta `nunca` como modelo de la view, para eos se crean una clase en la carpeta `Model` de mvc y mapeas la entidad de `entity framework` con la entidad de model de mvc.

Aqui se puede ayudar con [automapper](https://medium.com/@cdelgado1978/implementando-automapper-sin-perderte-en-el-camino-213e11af72c1), para hacerlo mas simple